# How dynamically add route to the react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How dynamically add route to react app? I tried to add routes in my app dynamically, but catch some problems here:

**component.jsx**

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default props => (
    <div className="App main-content">
            <Switch>
              {props.admin.routes.length
                ? props.admin.routes.map((route, i) => (
                    <Route
                      exact
                      key={i}
                      path={route.path}
                      component={route.component}
                    />
                  );
                )
                : null}
            </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

**props.admin.routes**

[image: good]

**react devTools**

[image: empty]

Props contains route data, but if I will link to `account/tickets`, I have got blank page. What can I do wrong?

**P.S.**

App contains `BrowserRouter` in the root component

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Have you tried to debug by using a simple JSX on the ```routes.component``` property like ```<div>tes1</div>``` ? Is it working?

Comment: @mfakhrusy Yes, I have. The same - blank page

Comment: I think this may have to do with not directly nesting the route under the switch,  I too am trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `render` props to the `Route` component:

```
<Switch>
  {this.props.admin.map((item, index) =>
    <Route
      path={item.path}
      exact
      key={item.id || index} // add new id to the data itself
      render={() => item.component}
    />
  )}
</Switch>
```

The reason is, by [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) documentation, `component` props can only accept a react component, not inline JSX. But you can use `render` to generate an inline JSX dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it also can't resolve my issue